# GestureDetector not working under IgnorePointer

Tags: flutter

I have the following code under a `SingleChildScrollView`. I used `IgnorePointer` so I can make the scrolling work. But now I am not able to make `GestureDetector` work because `IgnorePointer` is blocking it.

When I remove `IgnorePointer`, the `GestureDetector` works. Can I use other ways to make the scrolling work, or make the `GestureDetector` work while inside the `IgnorePointer`?

```
IgnorePointer(
                child:
                  Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                child: Container(

        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchfiveWpPosts(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    Map wppost = snapshot.data[index];
                    var imageurl = wppost['acf']['store_logo']['url'];

                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (_) => Detail()));
                                    },
                    child:  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Card(

                      child: 
                       Column(


                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

                        children: <Widget>[
                          //Image.network(imageurl),
                          Container(
                            //height: 170,
                            child: 

                            FadeInImage.assetNetwork(placeholder: 'assets/loading.gif', image: imageurl,
                            height: 170,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                          ),


                          Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 5, 10),
                          child: Text(wppost['title']['rendered'], style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.blueAccent,),),
                          ),


                        ],
                      ),

                  ),
                    ),
                  );

                  }, 
                );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },


      ),
                ),
              ),
                ),
```

Comment: so do not use `IgnorePointer` - i have no idea why you do that

Comment: The Scrolling doesnt work if i remove the IgnorePointer. The whole code is under SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: no, `SingleChildScrollView` works just fine without `IgnorePointer` - and if your case is `ListView.builder` inside `SingleChildScrollView` then you have to use a different approach since `ListView.builder` is pointless there